Filter out rows in 1:N LEFT JOIN where any row in child table fails condition
I have two tables, one which I will call D and one which I will call S, with a 1:N relationship between D and S. I currently have the following query that runs on these two:
SELECT d.*, s.*
FROM d
LEFT JOIN s ON s.d_id = d.id
WHERE coalesce(:status, d.status) = d.status

Now, this works well, but I would like to be able to filter on s.block_start and s.block_end, which are date times. That seems straightforward, but my goal is to filter out any row in D that corresponds to a row in S which doesn't fall within the date time bounds I set. My first thought was to join the above with the following query:
SELECT id
FROM (
    SELECT d.id, MIN(s.block_start), MAX(s.block_end)
    FROM d
    LEFT JOIN s ON s.d_id = d.id
    GROUP BY d.id
) WHERE block_start >= :start AND block_end <= :end

but this seems like a very inefficient query for what I'm trying to do. Does anyone know of the best-practice way to achieve this result?

"row in S which doesn't fall within the date time bounds" - they need to fall fully within the bounds to be targeted, or is it enough if they touch/overlap/contain the target range?

The canonical way is to show (relevant parts of) table definitions as CREATE TABLE scripts, and some sample values with INSERT scripts, and the usual stuff for performance questions as instructed here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info And clarify what result you actually need. Typically, it's neither d.*, s.* nor just the id

@Zegarek, I think overlapping is enough here.

@ErwinBrandstetter It is actually d.*, s.* and just id.

While there aren't huge numbers of rows in table s for each d.id, I expect this query to perform best:
SELECT *  -- retrieve all columns?
FROM   d
LEFT   JOIN s ON s.d_id = d.id
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM s
   WHERE  s.d_id = d.id
   AND   (s.block_start < :start
       OR s.block_end   > :end)
   )
-- AND  (d.status = :status OR :status IS NULL)

... when supported by one multicolumn index like:
CREATE INDEX s_d_id_start_end ON s (d_id, block_start, block_end);

Your use of LEFT JOIN indicates you don't want to exclude rows from d that have no related rows in s. Pay attention not to void that plan with conditions that demand rows from s after all. (Applies to both answers so far.)
If the table is vacuum'ed enough, you'll get index-only scans, where Postgres walks all index rows for each d_id, and filters for start & end. It can stop as soon as the first offending row is encountered. So many offending rows are good for the performance of this query.
The query is versatile in regard to what you want to retrieve eventually.
And it works well with or without filter on status.
More optimization is possible, depending on undisclosed details.

Good idea. While you use NOT EXISTS? Whether there are rows outside the range or not does not matter.

@ValNik: Yes, EXISTS is kind of "fire and forget" in that regard.

This did exactly what I needed, thank you.

Just as an aside, your note about the LEFT JOIN was well taken, but in general, all items in d will also be accompanied by at least one row in s so that particular issue isn't as important here.

If you want get only d.id you can take s.d_id (d.id=s.d_id) without JOIN.
Try
    SELECT s.d_id as id, MIN(s.block_start), MAX(s.block_end)
    FROM s
    WHERE s.block_start >= :start AND s.block_end <= :end
    GROUP BY s.d_id

Case when d.id is exists in D and not exists s.d_id then you will still filter such condition rows by date range(id,null,null). Therefore, join with d is not needed.
Case when you want some like d.* (several columns from d)
try
select * 
from d
inner join(
    SELECT s.d_id, MIN(s.block_start), MAX(s.block_end)
    FROM s
    WHERE s.block_start >= :start AND s.block_end <= :end
    GROUP BY s.d_id
 ) s ON s.d_id = d.id


There using LEFT or INNER join - the choice depends on the expected result. inner join matches your current query.
With the growth of N in the ratio d:s (1:N), the relative efficiency of such a query will be better.
Applying a date range filter before grouping and before  join is also preferable, the more so the narrower this filter is.

Your query reduces to a HAVING clause:
demo at db<>fiddle
SELECT d.id
FROM d
LEFT JOIN s ON s.d_id = d.id
GROUP BY d.id
HAVING MIN(s.block_start) >= :start
   AND MAX(s.block_end)   <= :end

And it's not really that inefficient, as long as you have this type of index in place:
create index on s(d_id,block_start,block_end);

Thing is, the description of your desired logic doesn't really match your code, or its reduced version:

my goal is to filter out any row in D that corresponds to a row in S which doesn't fall within the date time bounds I set

Not falling within could be:

Completely disjoined, where it both starts and ends entirely before or entirely after your target range.
Partially but not fully within, where it starts or ends inside the range, but stretches beyond the range.
It's wider than the entire range, and contains it whole. It doesn't fall within the range because it's the range that falls within it.

Among others. On top of that, you're aggregating, so the code accepts all d's that have at least one s above the lower bound, and another, not necessarily the same, which is under the upper bound.
There might be a faster index+query setup, depending on what exactly you're aiming to catch/skip.
